# getting the js error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: javascript

Tried to get length of the listbox:

```
var list = $.clientID('lstCategory');
alert(list.options.length);
```

This threw the exception:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property
>   or method.

Anybody please help.

Comment: So what should this `clientID()` function return? Did you write it?

Comment: For an accurate answer you should tell what $ is. A reference to a JS library?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be...

```
var list = document.getElementById('lstCategory');
```

instead of the $.clientID bit.

Here's an example... http://jsfiddle.net/um3uF/